# unable to install jscoverage in ubuntu 16.04 but it works in 14.04

Tags: 16.04, apt

I am unable to install jscoverage in 16.04 but able to install in 14.04

```
$ sudo apt-get install jscoverage 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package jscoverage
```

Note :: jscoverage_0.5.1-2_amd64.deb was not there in 16.04 but its in 14.04
Are you supporting jscoverage in 16.04 version or not
Thanks,
sekharK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such package on 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS repositories:

See [list search results on `packages.ubuntu.com`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=jscoverage):

> **Package jscoverage**
>      trusty (14.04LTS) (devel): Javascript code coverage [universe]
>      0.5.1-2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el

But you can install this package manually:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/j/jscoverage/jscoverage_0.5.1-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./jscoverage_0.5.1-2_amd64.deb
```

Then you can use it

```
$ jscoverage --version
jscoverage 0.5.1
Character encoding support: iconv
Copyright (C) 2010 siliconforks.com
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/license.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

---

I reported [bug 1788836](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jscoverage/+bug/1788836) to LaunchPad about missed packages on 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS. Homepage of the project says that project [is abandoned](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/):

> Note: Any future development of the JSCoverage code base will likely occur in the new JSCover project on GitHub, which reuses a substantial amount of JSCoverage code and aims for a high degree of backward compatibility with JSCoverage. JSCoverage itself is unlikely to have any further releases.

So it [was dropped](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jscoverage/+bug/1788836/comments/1) from Debian and then from Ubuntu.